# Automatic solver of four-color theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, coloring, online-resources, planar-graphs

Does anyone know of an app/online tool to automatically colour any map or image using the 4-colour theorem? (Taking a Black and white image as input).

Comment: Why are you looking for one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about mathematics, but is rather asking for a recommendation for an app/program that performs a specific function.

Comment: How does one use the $4$-colour theorem to colour a map?

Comment: As far as I recall, the proof is constructive, so it does yield an algorithm to colour a map.